# Python3 PyODBC issue from Windows7 to SQL Server

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

I am able to connect to remote SQL Server using port 1433, from SQL Server Management Studio v19.0.2 (on a Windows 7 PC). I'm able to configure Windows ODBC using 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server', and I'm successfully able to see the databases (but ODBC 17, 18 failed).

I need to connect from Python 3.8, but I get an error (spent much time, any help is much appreciated).

Code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};"
    "Server=tcp:server;"
    "PORT=1433;"
    "Database=db_name;"
    "UID=user;"
    "PWD=password;"
    "Trusted_Connection=no"
)
```

Error:

> conn = pyodbc.connect(
> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.\r\n (11004) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (11004)')

Comment: Windows 7 is very old and not longer supported, , but i think that you haven't enabled sql browser and/or enabled TCP connection for the server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? ODBC 11 supported SQL Server 2005-2014; all but *one* of those is completely unsupported (like Windows 7), and 2014 has about a *year* left of extended support only.

Comment: Is there any good reason you're using the ODBC 11 driver, instead of the later releases? The ODBC drivers were pretty meh for a very long time before MS made work of them again. Version 17.4 is the last version that supports Windows 7, and your connection string works for me using the 17 driver. Note that all versions of the ODBC driver require installing them first (there is a legacy native driver included with the OS, but that should not be used if at all avoidable).

Comment: Aside... `PORT` is not an ODBC Driver for SQL Server connection property. If you need to specify a port (and you don't if the server is listening on the default tcp/1433 port) you include it in the `SERVER` property, e.g. `Server=tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress,portNumberHere;`

Comment: Thanks for the informations. I cant change the windws version, it is 7. Odbc 11 on windows shows the databases, hope that means it is working. But not from Python. I will check the SQL version and also try to update odbc 17 and 18 and report, shortly.

Comment: widows7 odbc data source administrator - Shows error for odbc17 on windows7. But odbc11 works on that. Error of odbc17: (this is not python, its windows app).

Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.10.0003

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

TESTS FAILED!

Comment: Solved with pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe')
for row in cursor:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row['id'], row['name']))

conn.close()